# Send feedback from gmail without choose, only toast in my application

Tags: android, android-intent

Hear is my code

```
      @Click
public void btnSubmit() {
    if (validateInput()) {
        Intent send = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        send.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
        String uriText = "mailto:" + Uri.encode("sorathiya.payal1994@gmail.com") +
                "?subject=" + Uri.encode(edtName.getText().toString()) +
                "&body=" + Uri.encode(edtMessage.getText().toString());
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

        send.setData(uri);
        startActivity(send);           
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Thank You For Feedback", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

in above code G mail composer open, I do only toast in my application that send email, feedback send in background,how can I do??

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please rewrite it to have a better understanding on your goal?

Comment: How can I send feedback in  background only toast in application. in my application i get subject and feedback message from user and than user click on send button than feedback send through gmail without open gmail how can i do??/?